# Enter keydown and click event update image in ie 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, internet-explorer-7

I have a next button and a input tag, user can enter page number into the input,and hit enter to jump to the page, every page is an image,

like:

```
<img src="http://someurl.com/1_1.emf" >   // first page
<img src="http://someurl.com/2_1.emf" >   // second page
```

as you can see the only defference is the url , when updateing the page , i did not update the src attributes , but change the whole img tag.

the problem is that if I enter 2 in the input tag and hit enter , the image updated successfully, but when i click the next button the image just shows a white background, not matter how long i wait it will not render the image.

the enter keydown event and the click event are exactly same.but I notic that when use input to  update page, after hit the enter, there will be an loading circle beside the mouse pointer,but when click the next button there isn't.

any idea why???

code:

```
<input type="text" class="currentPage" id="docCurrentPage" value="1" onfocus="this.className='currentPage_focus'" onkeydown="jumpToPage(event,this.value)" onblur="this.className='currentPage'" />

window.jumpToPage = function(event, value) {
    var charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode;
    if (charCode == 13) {
        var num = parseInt(value);
        var totalPage = parseInt(doc.options.pageCount)
        if (num != 0 && num <= totalPage) {
            // doc.download(num)
            doc.download.apply(doc,[num])
        } else {
            doc._node.docPager.val(doc.currPage)
        }
    }
}


<a id="nextBtn" class="doc_right" onclick="openDocNextPage()" href="javascript:;" ></a>

openDocNextPage = function() {
    if (!doc.isLastPage()) {
        var totalPage = parseInt(this.options.pageCount);
        var pageNum = parseInt(this.currPage) + 1;
        if (pageNum != totalPage + 1) {
             this.download(pageNum);
        }
    }
}

 download: function(pageNum) {
        // debugger;

        if (pageNum != this.tempPage) {
            this.tempPage = pageNum || 1;
            if (this.options.id) {
                if (this.docType === 'emf') {
                    if (!this.downloading) {
                        this.getDoc(pageNum)
                    }
                } else if (this.docType === 'txt') {
                    this.loadDoc(this.getUrl(pageNum))
                    this.updatePageNum(pageNum)
                }
            } else {
                this.loadDoc(this.getUrl(pageNum))
                this.updatePageNum(pageNum)
            }
        }
    },
```

Comment: Can you actually show the code?

Comment: please wait a moment

Comment: Does `onclick="openDocNextPage(); return false;"` make a difference?

Comment: Nitpick:  there is no need to use JavaScript to add a class for focus. Just use `.currentPage:focus {} ` unless you are supporting really old browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
<a id="nextBtn" class="doc_right" onclick="openDocNextPage()" href="javascript:;" ></a>
```

to

```
<a id="nextBtn" class="doc_right" onclick="openDocNextPage(); return false;" href="#" ></a>
```

Comment: no still not work; however i just find out that if I add alert(1) into the last line of download function it will always work, why?

Comment: oh my bad , when i test your code ,i did not change the href to '#', your code works great, thank you so much. and please help me understand why href="javascript:;" wont work